# Delete row that is combination of two tables using button

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql

Basically what title says. The result of table display script and sql query creates table that combines two tables from SQL server on html page. We have been tasked to create button named "Delete" next to every row displayed. The problem is that books say and other users are using the a href with $row[ID] which is just one parameter. I need to "extract" two parameters to pass to delete.php to identify the rows in both tables. Then there is the second "POST" option if(isset($_POST))... But that can also only extract one value. Could someone please pass some knowledge on how to either "identify" values on row, where the button was pressed or to pass somehow two variables to delete.php or how to make POST method work passing two parameters. As I said, I cannot store the IDs in value that has to contain "delete"

```
echo('<table border="2">');
echo('<tr><td>"Název Nemocnice"');
echo('</td><td>"Adresa Nemocnice"');
echo('</td><td>"Název pojišťovny"');
echo('</td><td>"Kód pojišťovny"');
echo('</td></tr>');
foreach ($result as $r){
echo('<tr><td>' . htmlspecialchars($r['nazevNemocnice']));
echo('</td><td>' . htmlspecialchars($r['adresaNemocnice']));
echo('</td><td>' . htmlspecialchars($r['nazevPojistovny']));
echo('</td><td>' . htmlspecialchars($r['kodPojistovny']));
echo('</td><td><input type= "submit" name="deleteItem" value="Delete"');
echo('</td></tr>');
}
echo('</table>');
```

After mild update I was able to get it to work but there is very strange problem. It doesn't pass the whole value.

```
                    foreach ($result as $r){
                        echo('<tr><td>' . htmlspecialchars($r['nazevNemocnice']));
                        echo('</td><td>' . htmlspecialchars($r['adresaNemocnice']));
                        echo('</td><td>' . htmlspecialchars($r['nazevPojistovny']));
                        echo('</td><td>' . htmlspecialchars($r['kodPojistovny']));
                        echo('</td><td>');
                        echo('<form method="post" action="delete.php">');
                        echo('<input type="hidden" name="id1" value='.htmlspecialchars($r['nazevNemocnice']).'>');
                        echo('<input type="hidden" name="id2" value='.htmlspecialchars($r['adresaNemocnice']).'>');
                        echo('<input type="hidden" name="id3" value='.htmlspecialchars($r['nazevPojistovny']).'>');
                        echo('<input type="hidden" name="id4" value='.htmlspecialchars($r['kodPojistovny']).'>');
                        echo('<input type= "submit" name="deleteItem" value="Delete">');
                        echo('</form>');
                        echo('</td></tr>');
                    }
                    echo('</table>');
```

In the display  it prints "Hospital A"
When POST is used on submit, values transfered in hidden inputs are "inclomplete" So I get "Hospital" transfered. I tried echoing it on the delete page, and it prints first words only.

```
Hospital A -> Hospital
Address A -> Address
Insurance A -> Insurance
0101 -> 0101
```

Do you know what went wrong?

Comment: post delete.php page code

Comment: I don't have one.. I don't have a clue how to pass two variables e.g. nazevNemocnice AND nazevPojistovny
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("abc","abc","abc","abc");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$id = $_GET['nazevNemocnice']; 


// $id = (int)$_GET['nazevNemocnice'];

mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM XXX WHERE id='".$id."'");
mysqli_close($con);
header("Location: index.php");
?>

Comment: Just FYI your `delete.php` page is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use parametrised queries when dealing with user input. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply pass both tableId as hidden param to delete.php

```
echo('<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="tableOneID" value="'.$r['tableOneID'].'">' . htmlspecialchars($r['nazevNemocnice']));

echo('<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="tableTwoID" value="'.$r['tableTwoID'].'">' . htmlspecialchars($r['adresaNemocnice']));
```

something like this and that will help you to fetch tableOneID and tableTwoID of each row.

Answer (score 1):

You generally don't want to use an HREF (which is a GET request) to perform operations that are not [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence). (I.e., that result in a database change.) Instead use a form submission (which is a POST request.) Given that, adding multiple hidden values to identify multiple rows is simple.

```
<form method="post" action="...">
    <input type="hidden" name="id1" value="...">
    <input type="hidden" name="id2" value="...">
    <input type= "submit" name="deleteItem" value="Delete">
</form>
```

Comment: What if I already use post method to populate tables? Clicking submit will trigger the if (!empty($_POST)) condition and then queries to fill database will be loaded. Is there a way to diferenciate between these?

Comment: If you click the delete button, then `$_POST['deleteItem']` will be set to `"Delete"`. If you click some other button that submits to the same page, then (presumably) you'll have some other name for the submit button.

Comment: Or just submit to different pages.

Comment: Please help me one more time. Your suggestion works. Just not completely. See edited post

Answer (score 0):

You can use the button tag instead of the input tag if you want to pass in a different value but keep the label.

```html
<button type="submit" name="deleteItem" value="{$row[ID]}">Delete</button>
```